# Remove similar element in other class

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can remove similar element(ul) in class `.makhzan` after click on one of `111` Or `222` Or `333` by jquery in html?

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/nkNbc/

My try:

```
$('.class_show .tooltip_hover').live('click change', function(){
    $(this).closest('ul').remove();
    var value_bet = $(this).text();
    $(".makhzan .tooltip_hover li").filter(function () {
        var get = $(this).text() == value_bet;
        return get.closest('ul'); // This doesn't work for remove element ul
    }).remove();
});
```

Comment: use .parents('ul').eq(0) instead of closest http://api.jquery.com/parents/

Comment: booo jsfiddle not loadinfg....

Comment: Umm... what? Even with the fiddle I don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: you want to remove the other element that have the same text that the one you are clicking?

Comment: @MCSI - yes i want this, for remove tag ul in `.makhzan`. what do i do?

Comment: You have an error in your demo: <li> must be in <ul>, not <div>

Comment: @Adam - Why .parents() rather than .closest()?

Comment: @nachito I guess for his example it wouldn't matter.. but obviously just in case there is another ul inside of the ul so it grabs the parents element and not the next one. Because i think he wants to hide the parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `:contains` to sidestep the filter function:

```
$('.class_show .tooltip_hover').live('click change', function(){
    $(this).closest('ul').remove();
    var value_bet = $.trim($(this).text());
    $('.makhzan .tooltip_hover li:contains("'+value_bet+'")')
        .closest('ul').remove();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/nkNbc/4/

If you're using jQuery 1.7, however, you may as well get used to using `.on` instead of `.live`:

```
$(document).on('click change', '.class_show .tooltip_hover', function() {
    ...
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/nkNbc/5/

**UPDATE**

In light of nachito's comments -- If I were building this, I'd assign an attribute like `data-key="1"` to each `<li>` and match that instead of trying to match the exact text contents of an HTML element and risking a mismatch:

```
$(document).on('click change', '.class_show .tooltip_hover', function() {
    $(this).closest('ul').remove();
    var value_bet = $(this).find('li').data('key');
    $('.makhzan .tooltip_hover li[data-key="' + value_bet + '"]')
        .closest('ul').remove();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/nkNbc/6/

Comment: :contains will work great as long as the text is unique. I know in the example the values were simple, however it should be pointed out that if the <li> tags in .makhzan _contain_ rather than _equal_ `value_bet` they will be removed, e.g., clicking on `111` will remove `111` and `111222`.

Comment: @nachito True; using `.text` has a few limitations as well, since it strips out all HTML tags and may or may not preserve whitespace. The best choice depends a lot on exactly what OP wants to use this on.

Answer (score 0):

The [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter) function expects your callback function to return `true` or `false`. You should return `get` and then remove the `closest('ul')` on the filtered collection.

```
$('.class_show .tooltip_hover').live('click change', function(){
    $(this).closest('ul').remove();
    var value_bet = $(this).text();
    $(".makhzan .tooltip_hover li").filter(function () {
        return $(this).text() == value_bet;
    }).closest('ul').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help you, im not sure

```
$('.class_show .tooltip_hover li').click(function() {
    var li_text = $(this).text();
    $('.makhzan .tooltip_hover li').each(function() {
        if($(this).text() == li_text){
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
});
```

this will work only if the text is exactly the same.

maybe you have to use another type of comparison